# BibTeX and in-text citations

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I am starting with LaTeX and now I have a problem. I am writing a long document (thesis) and I have a specific LaTeX template which uses the BibTeX package to manage bibliography (as soon as I understand the code). In the past I used to use the `natbib` package which helps a lot when trying to insert in-text citations.

Now I cannot figure out how to implement the `natbib` in the main file. How can I 'force' the BibTeX pack to get in-text citations like:

> LaTeX is difficult (Guy et al., 2016).

Comment: Welcome! I think we need a Minimum Working Example (MWE) i.e. a small document showing what you are doing. If you are using a non-standard class or package and that's essential to the question, make sure to provide a link so we can find it. Right now, your question isn't very clear to me. BibTeX is not a package at all - you can't say `\usepackage{bibtex}`. It is, rather a programme you run to generate citations and bibliographies from a database of entries (`.bib` file). **natbib** is one package which enhances the LaTeX/BibTeX combo. So why not just `\usepackage{natbib}`?

Comment: You are using a template, please tell us which one. I am not a psychic like the guys who provided an answer. I think you just skipped/missed the little *la* and the template uses `biblatex`  which you are not prepare for. As a result, the citations look strange (no question marks, but bold cite key). So, just as @cfr, i want to see a MWE (or link to the template).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer I am using this template: https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~wannes.meert/adsphd/ but I cannot figure out how to use in-text citations, I tried adding the \usepackage{natbib} in the preamble of the main file, but it did not work.

Comment: Crosspost: https://github.com/wannesm/adsphd/issues/48

Answer (score 3):

That *template* does some funny things. It gives you many options, which as well means many limitations.

For example, you can add an option `biblatex` as class option to use the modern package, but `\bibliography` doesn't work anymore, because the macro is redefined. The `make` script does not run `biber` even though specified.

If you decide to do the classical way, you can change the `\bibstyle` (yes, it is called that way).  As soon as you load package `natbib`, the bibstyle is set to `plain` and can't be changed.

Having said that, i think this question arises from a template bug and should be closed.

To address the little comment in the question: LaTeX is not difficult if you are using the standard. Every template, that defines own commands and macros means extra confusion and more stuff to handle for a starter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to (a) load the `natbib` package with the option `authoryear`, (b) provide a `\bibliographystyle{<some style>}` instruction, and (c) use

```
\citep{<entry key>}
```

instructions to generate citation call-outs of the desired form.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Johannes is correct, and the template uses `biblatex`. If that is the case, then I guess your answer isn't that useful (though of course we'd need more information to be sure about this).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - You may very well be correct. Let's hope the OP clarifies his/her document setup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a bibliographical style. In this case:

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```